# How to sort the items in the comboBox1 from old to new?

Tags: c#, winforms

old on the top and the newest on the bottom.

now the date 28.09 is the at the top and at the bottom it's the 12.09 but I want that the 12.09 will be at the top as the oldest and the others to be sorted as the new ones.

[image: items in combobox1]

```
private void InitFolders()
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();

    // Get all subdirectories inside the specified root folder
    string rootFolder = lightningsDirectoryTextBox.Text;
    string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(rootFolder);

    sessionDirectories = subDirectories
        .Where(dir =>
        {
            int index = dir.IndexOf("Session_");
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                string sessionFolder = dir.Substring(index + 8);
                // Filter subdirectories that start with "Lightning"
                string[] subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
                if (subFolders.Any(subDir => subDir.Contains("Lightning") && Directory.GetFiles(subDir).Length > 0))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sessionFolder);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        })
        .ToList();

    if (sessionDirectories.Count > 0)
    {
        // Sort the session directories by name in descending order to get the last session
        sessionDirectories.Sort();
        sessionDirectories.Reverse();

        foreach (string sessionDirectory in sessionDirectories)
        {
            string[] subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(sessionDirectory);
            // Filter subdirectories that start with "Lightning"
            lightningDirectories = subFolders
                .Where(dir =>
                {
                    string folderName = Path.GetFileName(dir);
                    return folderName.Contains("Lightning") && folderName.Contains("_[");
                })
                .ToList();

            if (lightningDirectories.Count > 0)
            {
                lightningSelectionTrackBar.Enabled = true;
                imageSelectionTrackBar.Enabled = true;
                btnBrowseLightningsFolder.Enabled = true;
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;

                // Update lightningSelectionTrackBar.Maximum with the count of Lightning folders
                lightningSelectionTrackBar.Maximum = lightningDirectories.Count;

                // Set track bar properties based on the number of Lightning folders
                if (lightningDirectories.Count == 1)
                {
                    lightningSelectionTrackBar.Minimum = 1;
                    lightningSelectionTrackBar.Maximum = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    lightningSelectionTrackBar.Minimum = 1; // Start from 1 for multiple Lightnings
                    lightningSelectionTrackBar.Maximum = lightningDirectories.Count;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lightningSelectionTrackBar.Enabled = false;
                imageSelectionTrackBar.Enabled = false;
                lightningSelectionTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
                lightningSelectionTrackBar.Maximum = 0;
                imageSelectionTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
                imageSelectionTrackBar.Maximum = 0;
                btnBrowseLightningsFolder.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        // Select the last session
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.Enabled = false;
        lightningSelectionTrackBar.Enabled = false;
        imageSelectionTrackBar.Enabled = false;
        lightningSelectionTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
        lightningSelectionTrackBar.Maximum = 0;
        imageSelectionTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
        imageSelectionTrackBar.Maximum = 0;
        btnBrowseLightningsFolder.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I tried before adding the items to the combobox1 to make:

```
sessionDirectories.Sort();
```

but it didn't change much still it's adding the items like in the screenshot image.